# Servetel API integration with Google Sheet (Mobile Number Masking)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to integrate a "number masking" solution with the below API.

Basically I want my agent to call the customer from a google sheet. I don't want my agent to know the mobile number of my customer.

I will populate an agent sheet from my master sheet in which the customer mobile number is available. I want to give a link in the agent sheet using the below syntax.  The agent will open the agent sheet in his mobile and click a URL or tick box or button and the call will go to the customer through the API. Or I have to create a web page for the agent (with the list of all pending customer complaints), from where he can "click to call"

https://servetel.readme.io/docs/click-to-call-support

https://servetel.readme.io/reference#post_v1-click-to-call

The code generated in node.js is

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const url = 'https://api.servetel.in/v1/click_to_call';
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'xxx',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({agent_number: 12345, destination_number: 673544})
};

fetch(url, options)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
  .catch(err => console.error('error:' + err));
```

How to write it in appscript using urlfetchapp ?

The API key, agent numner and destination number will come from the master sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*UrlFetchApp functions similarly to fetch API and not many changes really need to be made.*

#### Code Example:

```
const url = 'https://api.servetel.in/v1/click_to_call'
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'xxx',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({agent_number: 12345, destination_number: 673544})
}

try {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)
  console.log(JSON.parse(res)
}
catch (e) {
  console.error('error' + e)
}
```

**NB:** Depending on whether the request URL requires the parameter `body` specifically, or whether this is generic for payload may mean you will have to rename the `body` key in options to `payload`.

#### References:

- [Class UrlFetchApp | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Comment: var axios = require("axios").default;

var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://rest.yahoofinanceapi.com/v11/finance/quoteSummary/AAPL',
  params: {modules: 'defaultKeyStatistics,assetProfile'},
  headers: {
    'x-api-key': 'YOUR-PERSONAL-API-KEY'
  }
};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
 console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
 console.error(error);
});
       @Rafa Guillermo  can you help with the above api

Comment: https://www.yahoofinanceapi.com/tutorial